# C: Trying to read characters from a file as float

Tags: c

**Running on Ubuntu 12.04 with gcc**

I have a text file that has the 10 values exactly as shown below:

> 0020.50 0020.49 0020.47 0020.46 0020.51 0020.50 0020.50 0020.49 0020.49 0020.50

I want to read these values in a buffer and then would like to do some calculations on it. All the values has to be treated as Floats.

So what I did is that I first read 10 characters in a buffer `buffer` and then used `atof()` to convert each value from character to  float and store in `bufferFloat`. But I see that the `bufferFloat` is not having correct values.

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
FILE *fp;
int i,x;
int read;

char * buffer;

buffer=(char *)malloc(20);

fp=fopen("Xvalues.txt","r");

read=fread(buffer,1,10,fp);

printf("no. of bytes read %d", read);

float bufferFloat[10];
int j; 

for(j=0;j<10;j++)
{

    bufferFloat[j]=atof(&buffer[j]); //converting characters to buffers 


}

int k;

for (k=0;k<10;k++)
{

    printf("printing buffers as floats: %f \n", bufferFloat[k]);

}

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ravi/Desktop/New/build# ./new1 
file opened sccesfully
no. of bytes read 10printing buffers as floats: 20.500000 
printing buffers as floats: 20.500000 
printing buffers as floats: 20.500000 
printing buffers as floats: 0.500000 
printing buffers as floats: 0.500000 
printing buffers as floats: 50.000000 
printing buffers as floats: 0.000000 
printing buffers as floats: 0.000000 
printing buffers as floats: 0.000000 
printing buffers as floats: 0.000000 
root@ubuntu:/home/ravi/Desktop/New/build#
```

Which is not what we have stored in the text file.

Please help me resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

**Here is my modified code using tokenization**

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()

{

FILE * fp ;

int read;
int i;

char * buffer;
buffer = (char *)malloc(2000);

fp=fopen("Xvalues.txt", "r");
if(fp==NULL)

{

printf("error reading the file");

}



//storing one line  in  buffer using fgets
if (fgets(buffer, 80, fp)!=NULL){

//    puts(buffer) ;

    }


//Tokanizing 


const char s[2]= " ";

//get the first token  

char * token;
token = strtok(buffer, s);


while (token!=NULL)
{

//printf("%s\n", token);
token  = strtok(NULL, s);

}


//converting to float
float bufferFloat[10000]; 
float ret;
ret =strtof(buffer, bufferFloat); 

for(i=0; i< 10; i++)
{
printf("float values are%f\n", bufferFloat[i]); 
}

fclose (fp);
return 0; 


}
```

**Still the output is incorrect**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ravi/Desktop/New# gcc test.c 
test.c: In function â€˜mainâ€™:
test.c:44:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
test.c:51:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
test.c:60:1: warning: passing argument 2 of â€˜strtofâ€™ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdlib.h:173:14: note: expected â€˜char ** __restrict__â€™ but argument is of type â€˜float *â€™
root@ubuntu:/home/ravi/Desktop/New# ./a.out 
float values are0.000000
float values are0.000000
float values are0.000000
float values are0.000000
float values are0.000000
float values are0.000000
float values are0.000000
float values are0.000000
float values are0.000000
float values are0.000000
root@ubuntu:/home/ravi/Desktop/New#
```

Comment: `first read 10 characters in a buffer`... there's the mistake.

Comment: Please indent your code properly when posting here. Also, you have some leftovers from C++ in your code so chances are that you compile C code with a C++ compiler. Don't do that these are two different languages.

Comment: try my solution.. Hope it will work (I tested with your data set)

Comment: `//converting characters to buffers` wut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing something like `read 10 characters in a buffer` is not going to give you 10 `float` [or whatever] in the `buffer`. This is not the way you should be reading from a file. My suggestion is

1. read a line from file using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).
2. tokenize the read buffer using proper delimiter [space in your case, maybe] using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).
3. convert each token to float using [`strtof()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof) (better than `atof()`) and store into array.

<sup>Notes:</sup>

<sup>1. `fgets()` reads and stores the trailing `\n`. Take care when tokenizing. 
2. The supplied buffer in `fgets()` should be long engouh to hold a complete *line* input from the file.</sup>

Also, worthy to mention, please check the success of `fopen()` call by putting a `NULL` check on `fp` after the call. Same goes for `fread()`.

---

EDIT:

Working code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXVAL 1024

int main()

{
        FILE * fp  = NULL;
        int read = 0;
        int i = 0;
        char * token = NULL;

        char buffer[MAXVAL] = {0};
        float bufferFloat[10] = {0}; //better way, use dynamic allocation

        fp=fopen("Xvalues.txt", "r");
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
                printf("error opening the file");
                return -1;      //don't continue
        }

        //storing one line  in  buffer using fgets
        if ( ! fgets(buffer, MAXVAL, fp) ){
            printf("error reading the file");
            return -2;      //don't continue
        }
        //Tokanizing 
        const char *s = " \n";      //because of fgets() stroing \n
        //get the first token  

        token = strtok(buffer, s);
        i = 0;
        while (token!=NULL)
        {
                bufferFloat[i++] = strtof(token, NULL);     //I used NULL used for simplicity, you follow the proper way.
                token  = strtok(NULL, s);
        }

        for(i=0; i< 10; i++)
        {
                printf("float values are%f\n", bufferFloat[i]);
        }

        fclose (fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Compile using

```
gcc test.c --std=c99
```

Run

```
./a.out
```

Output:

```
[sourav@broadsword temp]$ ./a.out 
float values are20.500000
float values are20.490000
float values are20.469999
float values are20.459999
float values are20.510000
float values are20.500000
float values are20.500000
float values are20.490000
float values are20.490000
float values are20.500000
[sourav@broadsword temp]$
```

Comment: Mention like atof() can be used to convert the string to float value

Comment: @Gopi Thanks, but redundant. OP already used that, so we can assume that part is known. :-)

Comment: @Gopi Never Mind . Updated with a better alternative. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh tried it using your method. Kindly see my modified code.

Comment: @user3891236 no no, not all at a time, do it one by one. also, `ret =strtof(buffer, bufferFloat);` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you have fixed  numbers as you mentioned you may use `fscanf()`

Guide - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm

Assumption - 10 numbers per line and it will not change

solution

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(){

FILE *fp;
char read;

fp=fopen("Xvalues.txt","r");


float array[10];

int i;

 do{
    read=fscanf(fp,"%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f",&array[0],&array[1],&array[2],&array[3],&array[4],&array[5],&array[6],&array[7],&array[8],&array[9]);
    fclose(fp);

    for(i=0 ; i< 10 ;i++){
        printf("%f ",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

 }while(read != EOF);

 return 0;
}
```

output

> 20.500000
>   20.490000
>   20.469999
>   20.459999
>   20.510000
>   20.500000
>   20.500000
>   20.490000
>   20.490000
>   20.500000

Comment: Just a suggestion, can't you use array?

Comment: Word of caution: `fscanf()` family function are not my personal fav. I would like to avoid them for many reasons. Don't forget to check the retur value of `fscanf()` for success (you're halfway there by using `read` variable).

Answer (score 0):

If data has been written as float into file then better to use fscanf() to get data in appropriate format.

Answer (score 0):

Read the line with `fgets()` the use `strod()` to parse it.

Anytime input data is in a *line*, consider `fgets()`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_EXPECTED_FLOAT_WIDTH (7)
#define MAX_EXPECTED_LINE_WIDTH(n)  (n * (MAX_EXPECTED_FLOAT_WIDTH + 1) + 2)

int ReadNfloat(FILE *stream, float *dest, int n) {
  char buffer[MAX_EXPECTED_LINE_WIDTH(n) * 2];  // I like 2x buffers
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stream) == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  char *p = buffer;

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    char *endptr;
    double number = strtod(p, &endptr);
    if (p == endptr) {  // no conversion
      return i;
    }

    // Code could do various tests. like to see if in expected range.
    if (number < 0 || number > 9999.99) {
      return i;
    }

    dest[i] = (float) number;
    p = endptr;
  }

  // Detect extra garbage
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *p) p++;
  if (*p) {
    return -1; 
  }

  return n;
}
```